# Link CMake package with bazel cmake_external

Tags: bazel, bazel-rules

To link pytorch c++ library with CMake, you really just need `find_package(Torch REQUIRED)` and use

```
-DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/absolute/path/to/libtorch
```

You can download the source here: https://download.pytorch.org/libtorch/nightly/cpu/libtorch-shared-with-deps-latest.zip
Tutorial for CMake is here: https://pytorch.org/cppdocs/installing.html

I have the following in my `WORKSPACE`:

```
new_local_repository(
    name = "torch",
    build_file_content = all_content,
    path = "third_party/libtorch",
)
```

And this in my `BUILD`

```
cmake_external(
    name = "torch",
    cache_entries = {
        "CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH": "/home/jackshi/projects/third_party/libtorch",
    },
    lib_source = "@torch//:all",
)
```

When I try to link to it, I get `<dir> does not appear to contain CMakeList.txt`
This is true, however, when you link it with `find_package(Torch REQUIRED)`, top level `CMakeList.txt` is not needed. CMake looks for `TorchConfig.cmake` . Can bazel create a target for this package without a top level `CMakeList.txt`? It should be looking for `TorchConfig.cmake` right?

Also, how does `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` work when the files are remote, acquired through `http_archive`, do you use `~/.cache/bazel` directory?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your link (https://download.pytorch.org/libtorch/nightly/cpu/libtorch-shared-with-deps-latest.zip) is not a source code, it's fully compiled library. Therefore there is not necessity for CMake, because it is already compiled.

`find_package` is a CMake feature, which find already **compiled** dependency using an algorithm, which search most common install paths. Library, which you want to find does not have to be compilled even in CMake. You do not want to use it here, because it's a CMake way to solve the problem

You can try three approches:

- In Bazel you can use library, which is already built. To do so just create an ordinary `cc_library` rule, where you add your compiled libraries `*.a` as `srcs`

```py
cc_library(
    name = "torch",
    srcs = glob(["lib/*.so", "lib/*.a"]),
    hdrs = glob(["include/**/*.h", "include/**/*.h"]),
    includes = ["include"],
)
```

That approach is rather bad, because you can not control the build process of this library. The more you compile from sources the better and more robust your build stack is.

- You can use [rules_foreign_cc](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_foreign_cc), which will run and execute CMake for you. See [example](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_foreign_cc/blob/main/examples/pybind11/BUILD). It is s a good approach, when there is no other way than calling a CMake
- I am not sure how you did your research, but it looks like [your library has a full support for Bazel](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/master/BUILD.bazel). Just use:

```py
# WORKSPACE file
 http_archive(
      name = "pytorch",
      urls = ["https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/archive/v1.7.1.tar.gz"],
      strip_prefix  = "pytorch-1.7.1",
  )

# and then in your BUILD file

cc_binary(
  name = "my_supper_binary"
  srcs = ["main.cpp"],
  deps = ["@pytorch//:torch"],
)
```

> Also, how does CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH work when the files are remote, acquired through http_archive, do you use ~/.cache/bazel directory?

No, for each action the Bazel setup a whole needed environment using a feature, which is called sandboxing. When you define `BUILD` file for your workspace created by for e.g. a `http_archive`, then all needed dependencies will be there, and you should not care about it, because that location is removed after the action is finished. With proper sandboxing implementation you can not even read `/home/jackshi/projects/third_party/libtorch` because that path is not in your `deps`. Bazel is really serious about it, because such a sneaky dependency can not be tracked, thus you could change something here, and Bazel will not recompile your target

However sometimes you want to add some dependency to your `cmake_external`. With rules_foreign_cc you can do something like this:

```py
configure_make(
    name = "apr",
    lib_source = "@apr//:all",
    shared_libraries = ["libapr-1.so"],
    static_libraries = ["libapr-1.a"],
)

configure_make(
    name = "apr_util",
    configure_options = [
        "--with-apr=$$EXT_BUILD_DEPS$$/apr",
    ],
    lib_source = "@apr_util//:all",
    shared_libraries = ["libaprutil-1.so"],
    static_libraries = ["libaprutil-1.a"],
    deps = [":apr"],
)
```

It is an autotools example, but it does not matter. `apr_util` target depends on `apr`. Therefore during the `apr_util` build the `apr` build artifacts will be available in the `$$EXT_BUILD_DEPS$$/apr`. That path is exclusively created to be used for that one particual build, and will be erased later